# Scroll an image quickly and smoothly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When scrolling an image in a browser using the scrollbars - the image scrolls quickly and smoothly. On the other hand, making a tight loop with [Graphics.DrawImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx), incrementing the location's X-coordinate by 1 each iteration - returns a slow motion. (It's also somewhat jerky even after making the Control `DoubleBuffered`.)

How can I get fast rendering like a browser's?

**EDIT**

```
void DoNow()
{
    Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, panel1.BackgroundImage.Size);
    Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, panel1.BackgroundImage.Size);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(panel1.BackgroundImage))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            rec2.Location = new Point(rec2.Location.X + 1, rec2.Location.Y);
            g.DrawImage(image, rec1, rec2, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            panel1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to answer your question (which is also too broad). It's fairly simple to implement fast scrolling (even for huge images) as long as it's implemented efficiently. Incrementing position by 1 pixel per scroll bar move is likely the wrong approach - you need to rely on the ratio of visible vs hidden size of the image.

Comment: @xxbbcc The code has only - `g.DrawImage(image, rec1, rec2, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);` and `panel1.Refresh();`. Without it - nothing would get updated. The rest is just creating the `Graphics` and a loop. Incrementing by more than 1 was too jerky to even be considered.

Comment: "creating the `Graphics`"... are you creating the graphics object yourself? You shouldn't be doing that, it should be provided to you via the `Paint` event arguments.

Comment: @ispiro Why do you have that `for` loop for drawing? You redraw the image 100 times... if you want to do animation, you need to use a timer instead. If this is in response to scrolling, you need to invalidate the relevant part of the panel and repaint that in the `Paint` event (or whatever it's called, I always forget the name :)  ).

Comment: Why use DrawImage? Any why on a Panel without Doblebuffering?? Why not use a PictureBox in a Panel with AutoScroll???

Comment: @TaW The scrolling will be by the program, not by the user so I can't use any built-in scrollbars. A PictureBox was my first choice, when that was too slow - I tried a Panel - with the same result. It _is_ Doublebuffered as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: _The scrolling will be by the program, not by the user so I can't use any built-in scrollbars_ Well, that doesn't exactly sound like what a browser does.. but you still can use the same mechanism: Move the Location of the PictureBox inside the Panel. But animation will __never__ be smooth in Winforms; it is a built-in limitation.

Comment: @xxbbcc The loop is just for a simple working example - so you can see how slow it is. There won't be any user-scrolling so I can't use scollbars (also - they actually don't work so well with large images.) As for using the `Paint` event - why would that be any better??

Comment: @ispiro If you're trying to do animation, you need to use a timer, not a tight loop. You need to establish a movement vector, that will give you X / Y pixels per second (or whatever time unit you want) and then you need to move the image at that speed in the timer.

Comment: @TaW a) I already tried moving a Panel behind a Panel before asking my question. It proved not much better. b) `But animation will never be smooth in Winforms; it is a built-in limitation.` - whoa - that would be the answer! Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @xxbbcc Yes. I realize all that. This was just to show the limitation. Moving more than one pixel at a time was not smooth enough. (and one - not fast enough) that's why I'm asking this question. (According to TaW - It's some Winforms limitation.)

Comment: @ispiro It's perfectly possible to create smooth animation in Winforms - I did it several times in the past. You need to add more details to your question about why you're trying to move a picture by 1 pixel at a time. As it is, your question is way unclear.

Comment: _Do you have a source for that?_ About 34 trillion posts here ;-) - The problem is that for smooth moving animations you need to stay in sync with the monitor and that's not possible with winforms. There are a few weird attempts to workaround but the best bet is to either give up on the goal or on winforms and go for WPF or UI with the upcoming win2D.. DirectX has it built-in and WPF is using that and Win2D a friendly subset, but I haven't mastered either..

Comment: @ xxbbcc: I'd __love__ to learn about how to move event a circle smoothly across the screen. Never saw an example, and I have been looking..

Comment: @TaW Define smoothly, then, maybe we're talking about something different.

Comment: @TaW Ah, ok, I just saw your comment. I agree with you then - doing this without _any_ tearing is very hard, to say the least, using GDI or GDI+. When I said smooth animation is possible, I didn't mean tear-free animation.

Comment: Smoothness: You know it when you see it, and I have never seen a movement that doesn't start to get jerky after a second or so.. Note that this implies a certain slowness, fast movements look better but slow movements just don't work. I'd love to be able to scroll text smoothly but It's  just not possible, I hate to admit (being a big fan of good ole Winforms..)

Comment: @TaW If you mean "smoothly" (not tear-free) then it's definitely possible - I indeed did that many times. It depends on keeping track of time between movements because the execution rate of the code is not guaranteed to be constant. So in each update during the animation, a different distance may have to be covered for smooth movement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950294/how-can-i-get-rid-of-jerkiness-in-winforms-scrolling-animation

Comment: @ispiro See the link above. Even that won't give you completely tear-free animation (no control over vsync) but it results in fairly smooth movement.

Comment: @TaW OK. So perhaps it's time to move on to WPF... I didn't realize that might make a serious difference. Thanks.

Comment: @xxbbcc Thanks for all the input. (Just a note: if you mean animating a sprite - it's much less work than moving over a million pixels.)

Comment: @ispiro If you're trying animate huge images, you need to use DirectX. WinForms can deal with reasonable animation pretty well but full-screen high-quality animation is way out of scope for it.

Comment: It seems from the comments like the answer to my question is that browsers use hardware acceleration which is unavailable to Winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from the comments like the answer to my question is that browsers use hardware acceleration which is unavailable to Winforms. (Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Since the commentators didn't post their answers for a couple of days, I'm undeleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a Panel object with the scroll bars set to Auto.  Place a picturebox as a child object with the size mode set to Auto.  The picture box will expand to the size of the image that you assign to it.  Since the picture box will expand to be larger than the panel, the panel's scroll bars will appear.  When you scroll the image using the panel, it will be smooth.

If you still want to manually provide the drawing yourself, you are getting the "flicker" because the Invalidate method automatically performs background erasing which is not performed during the OnPaint event.  You need to subclass the parent control that you are drawing on and override the OnPaintBackground event.  Like below:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
   // base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
}
```

Also, remember to perform ALL drawing during the OnPaint event and use the e.Graphics object.